# No Module named <module name> when running a nested module

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Here's my file structure:

```
/src
  /module1
    __init__.py
    foo.py
  /module2
    __init__.py
    main.py
```

In main.py I import something from foo.py:

```
from module1.foo import Foo
```

This is my vscode launch.json:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File (Integrated Terminal)",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal"
        },
    ]
}
```

I press Debug in Visual Studio Code to start the project from main.py and get the following error:

```
No Module named 'module1'
```

Why? How can I fix this issue?

Comment: This not a standard way to set things up, so you're going to need to either [make `src` a package (with `__init__.py` file), then `from ..module1.foo import Foo`], or add the `src` directory to your path, either with `PYTHONPATH` or `sys.path`

Comment: I added an empty /src/__init__.py and changed the import to ```from ..module1.foo import Foo```. I get the following error: ```attempted relative import beyond top-level package```...

Comment: That approach will only work if your entrypoint to is in (or above) `src`.  If it's in one of your modules (I guess it's probably `main`, isn't it...) then that approach won't work.

Comment: So what do I do? Is the only option to move main.py up a directory?

Comment: No, the other two options with changing your path should work (either by the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable or `sys.path` in your code.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was able to solve the problem by adding the PYTHONPATH variable to the launch.json file.

Just like this:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File (Integrated Terminal)",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "env": {
                "PYTHONPATH": "${workspaceRoot}"
            }
        },
    ]
}
```